# Issues with rebooting on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, 16.04, uefi

I have recently got a new Asus GL752VW laptop. It has a i7 6700HQ, a GTX 960M and 8GB of RAM. Everything in Ubuntu 16.04 works fine, except when I try to reboot, the screen turns black and it just hangs/freezes. I have deleted quiet splash from the grub file and before the reboot everything appears with an OK mark next to it. I have also tried adding acpi=off, reboot=efi/pci/etc., almost every single thing out there, even updated the kernel to 4.8rc3. Is there anything else I could try that might work, or is there at least a workaround or something that I've missed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I read it correctly, your problem only occurs at **reboot**, correct? When you reboot, trying hitting the ESC key, and see if it puts up a textual screen with some clues as to what's happening? Also, what size swap file do you have? In terminal, you can type **swapon** to find out. Cheers, Al

Comment: The swap size is 8GB, same as the RAM memory.

Comment: Your swap if fine. Try the ESC key trick and report back. Cheers, Al

Comment: Alright, I've just uploaded a youtube video showing exactly what's happening: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n6zTcjwsnJs . Hope it will be helpful

Comment: The ESC key trick does show the reboot sequence, but any errors are caught behind the black screen. Try rebooting from terminal, whilst making another video. Watch for errors, In terminal, type **sudo reboot**. Cheers, Al

Comment: I've uploaed another video, same thing, no errors showing up: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=607tTbg5rAk

Comment: Viewing the reboot vs shutdown text messages, they look alike, except shutdown does a power off at the end, whereas the reboot just goes through the same sequence, except that it doesn't power off at the end. One last thing to try... boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD and see if reboot fails there also. Cheers, Al

Comment: Yea, it seems that if I boot into the Live DVD and I do the normal reboot (top-right corner, click on restart), it seems that it works. Reboot worked fine and I was able to see the Asus logo-screen back on and after that I was able to boot into Ubuntu without any problems.

Comment: Reboot the computer, noting the EXACT time. It'll freeze, then manually reboot. Then in terminal, **cd /var/log**, then **more syslog**, looking at the date/time, find the last entries before the system boot starts logging entries. Look for text that might indicate errors. Cheers, Al

Comment: This is the whole syslog file from when it starts the reboot sequence:

https://www.mediafire.com/?rm29l486b9o1ww1

I honestly don't really know what all those things mean, hope you can figure it out. Thank you very much yet again, for helping me out.

Comment: Have you installed any snap applications? Played with snap? In terminal, type **ls /etc/modprobe.d** and tell me if you see a bunch of blacklist filenames. Cheers, Al

Comment: This is what shows up: http://i.prntscr.com/a12c6eb5f19f428ab78855ec1121a4cf.png

Comment: Are you sure you typed that command correctly? Also, you didn't answer my question about snaps. Reboot the computer, choose advanced options from GRUB, choose fsck. Cheers, Al

Comment: I don't even know what snaps is, so no, I don't think I've ever used that. Gonna try the fsck in a sec. That is exactly what shows up in the terminal.

Comment: I have just finished doing the fsck. Everything had a green mark next to it. There were no errors encountered.

Comment: Based on the fact that the **ls /etc/modprobe.d** returned such a wrong answer, and the reboot problems that you're having, I think the only solution is to reinstall Ubuntu. If you reinstall into the same directory, it'll keep /home for you. Cheers, Al (I'll post this as an answer, and you can vote/accept it, if you can).

Answer (score 1):

After a lengthy discussion... Based on the fact that the **ls /etc/modprobe.d** returned such a wrong answer, and the reboot problems that you're having, I think the only solution is to reinstall Ubuntu. If you reinstall into the same partition, it'll keep /home for you. Cheers, Al